# How does the Eldritch Claw Tattoo bonus to unarmed strikes interact with the fighting style Unarmed Fighting?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, unarmed-combat, fighting-style

I have an unarmed fighter with the Eldritch Claw Tattoo making their unarmed strikes +1 magical attacks. This being the case, how does this interact with the Unarmed Fighting fighting style which deals 1d4 to a grappled target? Would it be 1d4+1 magical damage?

Comment: Related: [Would the Insignia of Claws interact with the Fighting Style: Unarmed Fighting turning magical the bludgeoning damage to one creature grappled by you?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197397) [Can the damage from the Hunter's Mark spell be added to the damage from the Unarmed Fighting fighting style at the start of the character's turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196142)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4):

## Sadly it doesn't.

The  Eldritch Claw Tattoo says:

> Magical Strikes. While the tattoo is on your skin, your **unarmed**
> **strikes** are considered magical for the purpose of overcoming immunity
> and resistance to nonmagical attacks, and you gain a +1 bonus to
> attack and damage rolls with **unarmed strikes**.

But the Combat Style says:

> **Unarmed Fighting.** Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage
> equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier on a hit. If you aren't wielding
> any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll, the d6 becomes
> a d8.
>
> **At the start of each of your turns, you can deal 1d4 bludgeoning**
> **damage to one creature grappled by you.**

Sadly the 1d4 don't seems like a unarmed strikes to me, **but ask the GM**. It doesn't look like a game breaker and you have already invested a Combat style and an attuned magic item .

Comment: Might be a RAW vs RAI/RoC scenario. DM seems like a cool guy I'll run it by them. Thanks!

Comment: @iScreamsalad - I strongly doubt it's RAI either.  It seems clear that the damage you do from grappling a creature is not an unarmed strike (or any kind of attack), especially as it has a different damage die to the preceding paragraph.  As such I see no reason or argument for expecting it to benefit to modifiers to unarmed strikes.

Comment: Fair. I'll make my case for RoC then and accept what ever judgement comes to pass. Thanks for the input!